# Prevent onmouseout when hovering the popup (not the child elements) pure js

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `<a>` element which when hovered, displays a popup. For now, I was just able to do that when `onmouseleave` the popup disappears which is good bc I want it so.

The problem comes that the popup will disappear when I try to hover it. I looked around but every similar question involved a child element, which in this case I lack.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onmouseenter="showCartPopup()" onmouseleave="hideCartPopup()"></a>
(...)
<div id="popup"></div>
```

How can I achieve the effect I'd like? Can I somehow create like a mask around the link and the div? Thanks!

Edit:

js:

```
  function showCartPopup(){
    cart_popup = document.getElementById('popup')
    cart_popup.classList.add('show')
  };

  function hideCartPopup(){
    cart_popup = document.getElementById('popup')
    cart_popup.classList.remove('show')
  };
```

Comment: As you already guessed, why don't you just wrap both nodes in another div and add the javascript methods to that wrapper node instead of the anchor. However, you can achieve this effect with pure css, which is better as it will reduce the blocking time (or the evaluation time, however) of your browser which again increases your pagespeed ratings.

Comment: What is your show and hide code look like? easiest solution is to nest, but it is possible to add checks to not hide

Comment: @marks yes, the only problem is that the two elements are distant and the popup is generated, how can I wrap both in this case? To my knowledge, I can't

Comment: If its like on the other corner of the page or something, it's not the best to go with hover-events anyways I guess. Otherwise, you will leave the element which triggers the open with your mose, but then, how do you close it again if it should stay open? By going back to hover it again?! UX would be better if you simply change the toggle to a click listener instead of a hover event then

Comment: @epascarello code added. Could you explain it more in detail?

Comment: @marks well, click listener is not an option here, since the link redirects you to the cart.

Comment: But how far can it be apart then?! I guess you are talking about a cart icon. And usually the popup is right next to it?! If its not, really, its weird ;) And if its more or less close, why would you not be able to wrap it in a `position:relative` container and make the popup `position: absolute`

Comment: @marks yes it's exactly the scenario that you're describing. The popup is in effect directly under the icon, but I didn't create it, it's an app integrated previously in the website. That's why I say it's generated, the popup code than is added at the bottom of the page. EDIT: I could create a wrap around the popup, but I'd like to have like a dent on the icon. I'll like more into it.